# Subscribe scope is outside of components scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angularJS component:

```
export function setDisplayTaskDetailView(showTaskDetailView: boolean): void {
    if (showTaskDetailView !== null && window.device.mobile()) {
        showTaskDetailView$.onNext(showTaskDetailView);
    }
}

@Component('TaskHandling', {
    selector: 'task-overview-detail',
    templateUrl: '/TaskHandling/_Overview/TaskOverviewSomething.html'
})

class TaskOverviewComponent {

    public showTaskDetailView: boolean;

    $onInit() {
        this.observeTaskUpdates();
    }

    private observeTaskUpdates(): void {
        showTaskDetailView$
            .subscribe(value => {
                this.showTaskDetailView = value;
            });
    }
}
```

And from my route I have:

```
Xyz.TaskHandling.setDisplayTaskDetailView(params.showTaskDetailView);
```

When a user navigates to the above route it passes a true/false value to the `setDisplayTaskDetailView` function in the component.

The component passes the value into a stream and in the component I subscribe to that stream to pass the value to a class member. When I log the `this.showTaskDetailView` inside of the subscribe I get the value passed through the route.

But when I log the `this.showTaskDetailView` inside of the `$onInit` I get a undefined. Adding a setTimeout on the log in the $onInit doesn't change that value, so it doesn't look like a timing issue but more like a scope issue.

Any suggestions?

//edit. When I add a setTimeout to the `setDisplayTaskDetailView` function the value is correctly set inside of the class.

Comment: is `showTaskDetailView$` a `subject` or `BehaviorSubject` ?

Comment: It took me a bit of debugging, but the issue wasn't the scope. it's the timing. The exported function got executed before the component was initialized.